# How analytically solve $ax^2-b \sqrt{x}+c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How analytically solve $ax^2-b \sqrt{x}+c=0$, where a, b, c are positive constants? mathematica gives long complex solutions but not sure if it's reliable.

Comment: Don't tell mathematica about it. On the other hand, this is an equation of the fourth degree, what did you expect?

Comment: It’s a quartic polynomial in $\sqrt{x}$. There is a quartic formula, which shouldn’t be too bad since this is a somewhat “depressed” quartic.

Comment: *not sure if it's reliable* Use *Mathematica* to verify that they satisfy the equation.

Comment: Letting $u=\sqrt x,$ it becomes a quartic if equation in $u.$

Comment: What do you mean by "analytic?"

Comment: preferably to obtain x as an explicit function of a,b,c

Comment: If you want an explicit function, once you have substituted $u = \sqrt{x}$ as mentioned above, you merely need to use the [Ferrari/Cardano solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation). They're not easy, but they give explicit solutions, and more than likely it'll be the same expressions Mathematica gives.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\sqrt x=y$ and we instead divide the entire equation by $a$; this works without loss of generality. We can then get the quartic $y^4-by+c=0$, which can be solved using methods described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#Ferrari%27s_solution). Once roots for $y$ are found, you can then find possible values for $x$. You will have to make sure you do not obtain any extraneous solutions; for example, although the solution $y=-1$ would suggest $x=1$ as $y^2=1$, this doesn't work as square roots are always positive.